# Docker container can't ping out side of network

Tags: linux, networking, docker, linux-containers

I'm studying docker containers and now I'm trying to setup a network for docker containers.

Docker basically uses a `'docker0'` bridge that has`172.17.0.0/16` network and this network is not the same host network.

I want the docker container and host container to use the same network.
So now I am trying to make up docker container's network without 'bridge driver'.

I am using the `192.168.77.0/24` network by using sharer.
I want the host and docker container to use this network.

I referenced here - https://docs.docker.com/v1.7/articles/networking/#how-docker-networks-a-container.

Below are the commands that I tried to make up the network for containers.
All the commands were ran as the root user.

```
# ifconfig eth0 promisc

# docker run -i -t --net=none --name net_test ubuntu_net /bin/bash
# docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' net_test
# 14673 
# pid=14673 

# mkdir -p /var/run/netns
# ln -s /proc/$pid/ns/net /var/run/netns/$pid 

# brctl addbr my_bridge 
# brctl addif my_bridge eth0 
# ifconfig my_bridge 192.168.77.250 up 
# route del default gw 192.168.77.1 
# route add default gw 192.168.77.1 
# ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0 up 

# ip link add veth0 type veth peer name veth1 
# brctl addif my_bridge veth0 
# ip link set veth0 up 

# ip link set veth1 netns $pid 
# ip netns exec $pid ip link set dev veth1 name eth0 
# ip netns exec $pid ip link set eth0 address 12:34:56:78:9a:bc 
# ip netns exec $pid ip link set eth0 up 
# ip netns exec $pid ip addr add 192.168.77.251/24 broadcast 192.168.77.255 dev eth0 
# ip netns exec $pid ip route add default via 192.168.77.1
```

After these commands the docker container can ping to host, and the host can ping to the docker container but the container can't ping to the outside network.

Below is routing table in host after executing commands.

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.77.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 my_bridge
172.17.0.0      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.77.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 my_bridge
```

Below is routing table in the docker container after executing

```
commands.Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.77.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.77.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

but the docker container can't ping to gateway(192.168.77.1) too.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop verison.
and I didn't set any firewalls.

Am I setting anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: At this point you need to make sure that the host is receiving that traffic and forwarding it to its own outside gateway.  For more assistance, you'd need to provide details on the host's route and firewall rules to handle that.